# I can't save or find a document into MongoDB using Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using nodeJS for the first time, and I'm trying to do an application that connects to MongoDB via Mongoose.

I've installed MongoDB, NodeJS and Mongoose(via npm) successfully.

**My problem is:**
When I connect my node application through mongoose does not show any error, but when I try to insert a document, it just doesn't do anything at all. Freezes at the save line.

This is my code

```
var express  = require('express');
var app      = express();                             
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
...
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/exampleDB');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error:'));

var someModel = mongoose.model('someModel', {
    name : String
});

app.get('/api/todos', function(req, res) {
  var awesome_instance = new someModel({ name: 'awesome' });
  console.log("about to save the document");
  awesome_instance.save(function (err) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
  });
});

app.post('/api/todos', function(req, res) {

});
...
app.listen(8080);
console.log("App listening on port 8080");
```

Using a mongo client I can see my db, but not the collection that the code should have created. Also my mongoDB detects the connection from nodeJS. I just don't know what could be happening.

This is what my server.js (node) is showing

```
$ node server.js
App listening on port 8080
about to save the document
GET /api/todos - - ms - -
```

This is my mongo client

```
$ ./mongo
MongoDB shell version v4.0.0
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
MongoDB server version: 4.0.0
use exampleDB
switched to db exampleDB
show collections
exampleCollection
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I tested what you are trying to do on a simple node.js app with just your model and save method. Worked with no issues. Created the collections and saved. I did not use express however  so this might be the issue.

Comment: Your code is working fine on my machine. It saved the document without any issue. So please check your node modules and machine environment.

Comment: Oh, that's very confusing then. Is it possible that Windows is blocking Mongo 27017 port? I checked on security and can't find anything. I also tried without express, yes, and did the same. Do you have Mongo Community installed as a service?

Answer (score 0):

Let your `get` this and see if it works.

```
var express  = require('express');
var app      = express();                             
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/exampleDB', { useNewUrlParser: true });
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error:'));

var someModel = mongoose.model('someModel', {
    name : String
});

app.get('/api/todos', async function(req, res) {
var awesome_instance = new someModel({ name: 'awesome' });
await awesome_instance.save()
});

app.post('/api/todos', function(req, res) {

});
app.listen(8080, ()=>console.log("App listening on port 8080"));
```

Comment: I tried that, thank you for the suggestion. It did exactly the same. I think is more related with the database. If I log something after the .save() method, it logs it correctly.